# Unresolved top level overloading

Tags: haskell

Task is to find all two-valued numbers representable as the sum of the sqrt's of two natural numbers.
I try this:

```
func = [sqrt (x) + sqrt (y) | x <- [10..99], y <- [10..99], sqrt (x) `mod` 1 == 0, sqrt (y) `mod` 1 == 0]
```

Result:

> Unresolved top-level overloading  Binding             : func
>   Outstanding context : (Integral b, Floating b)

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you take this the wrong way: you better work with squares...

Comment: `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a`, `mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`. What number is both Integral and Floating? Also, once you've fixed the types, what does it mean for a number to be congruent to zero, mod one? One is not a very useful modulus.

Comment: Use `floor` instead of `\`mod\` 1 == 0`.

Comment: This might actually be the monomorphism restriction. Try giving `func` an explicit type signature.

Comment: @amalloy it's helpful in languages that allow floating point modulo (in Python, for example, `2.5 % 1 == 0.5`). In this case I think `\`mod\` 1` is just checking if the number is whole.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because of a conflict between these two types:

```
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

Because you write `mod (sqrt x) 1`, and `sqrt` is constrained to return the same type as it takes, the compiler is left trying to find a type for `x` that simultaneously satisfies the `Floating` constraint of `sqrt` and the `Integral` constraint of `mod`. There are no types in the `base` library that satisfy both constraints.

A quick fix is to use [`mod' :: Real a => a -> a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#v:mod-39-):

```
import Data.Fixed
func = [sqrt (x) + sqrt (y) | x <- [10..99], y <- [10..99], sqrt (x) `mod'` 1 == 0, sqrt (y) `mod'` 1 == 0]
```

However, from the error you posted, it looks like you may not be using GHC, and `mod'` is probably a GHC-ism. In that case you could copy the definition (and the definition of the helper function `div'`) from [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.Fixed.html#mod%27).

But I recommend a more involved fix. The key observation is that if `x = sqrt y`, then `x*x = y`, so we can avoid calling `sqrt` at all. Instead of iterating over numbers and checking if they have a clean `sqrt`, we can iterate over square roots; their squares will definitely have clean square roots. A straightforward application of this refactoring might look like this:

```
sqrts = takeWhile (\n -> n*n <= 99)
      . dropWhile (\n -> n*n <  10)
      $ [0..]

func = [x + y | x <- sqrts, y <- sqrts]
```

Of course, `func` is a terrible name (it's not even a function!), and `sqrts` is a constant we could compute ourselves, and is so short we should probably just inline it. So we might then simplify to:

```
numberSums = [x + y | x <- [4..9], y <- [4..9]]
```

At this point, I would be wondering whether I really wanted to write this at all, preferring just

```
numberSums = [8..18]
```

which, unlike the previous iteration, doesn't have any duplicates. It has lost all of the explanatory power of why this is an interesting constant, though, so you would definitely want a comment.

```
-- sums of pairs of numbers, each of whose squares lies in the range [10..99]
numberSums = [8..18]
```

This would be my final version.

Also, although the above definitions were not parameterized by the range to search for perfect squares in, all the proposed refactorings can be applied when that is a parameter; I leave this as a good exercise for the reader to check that they have understood each change.